# Appium Inspector doesn't respond to click on the app image

Tags: android, eclipse, automation, appium, appium-desktop

New to Appium. Its Inspector (GUI version) doesn't respond to any click on the app image (no logs on the server, no App Source content either after clicking). If "Tap By Coordinates" is clicked, it generates logs on the server only. I tried both appium-desktop-Setup-1.0.2-beta2.exe and appium-desktop-web-setup-1.6.2.exe (v1.8.1), the results are the same.

The real test phone used is Moto X Sprint (Android 4.2.2)
The beginning of the log is copied below, plus the code.

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.8.1
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   sessionOverride: true
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/sessions
[HTTP] {}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getSessions() with args: []
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getSessions() result: []
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 2 ms - 40
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity","appPackage":"com.android.vending","deviceName":"My Phone", ... ...
```

... ...
... ...

//My code

```
package tests;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class AppiumTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Set the Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "My Phone");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "LXSZ2A0007"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.2.2");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.vending");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");

        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        try {
                AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Note that it was pointed to "Google Play" on the top (see a screenshot below). No responses no matter where I pointed to on the image.

[Screenshot of the App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiTv2.jpg)

Comment: plz share your code and appium inspector point to your element

Comment: Your questions were answered by re-editing my post. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Gaurav, any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `UIAutomatorViewer` to find the elements, which you can find under your Android sdk.

Comment: uiautomatoreviewer worked after downgrading my JRE 9 to JRE 8. Thank you very much, Gaurav.